# How do I block/lock floating apps programmatically

Tags: android, mobile-development

Hi there i am working on a Applock.I am using a service to check top activity I use package and class name from ActivityManager getRunningTasks(); If this app is blocked I cover it with my own activity.But the **issue** is floating apps like LG - QSLIDE apps. Is there anyway to handle(block/lock)these apps as floating apps comes up over my blocking screen.Please guide me in right direction.

Comment: what type of lock screen your are providing Activity or adding view to window manager ?

Comment: Whenever blocked app appears in foreground I show my own app screen over it and if user provides correct password then i simply finish my activity,So user can use that particular app.Here is link of my app on play store
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.infoweise.applock

Comment: But floating apps like floating calculator or other apps that are available on play store creates issue.

Comment: actual case, floating apps are added to window manger,my suggession is to add lock screen view to window manger from your background service

Comment: Let me try. Thank you so much.

Comment: glad to help u.let me know if have any issue.